# How does the 'phase' of a cosine wave become 'pi' when it transitions from positive to negative?

Tags: filter-design, phase, cosine

I was watching this video lecture on filters where this professor says that:

> The phase of a cosine wave $\cos(\omega)$ is 0 till $\omega=\pi/2$. As soon as $\omega$ goes beyond $\pi/2$, i.e when $\cos(\omega)$ becomes negative, its phase becomes $\pi$.

I couldn't understand this. How can $\cos(\omega)$ have phase in itself if it is just a plain normal cosine function? What is the physical interpretation of this phase?

Comment: See my comment below

Answer (score 1):

The statement in the video is, at best, misleading. Normally, when people speak of the "phase" of a sinusoidal function $\cos \omega$, they are talking about the value of $\omega$. For instance, when we say that a wave undergoes a "phase shift", we mean that the value of $\omega$ has changed. More information on this definition of the word "phase" is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves).

As noted by Jazzmaniac in comments, we could also try to interpret the statement by regarding the value of $\cos \omega$ as a complex number $z$. In polar representation we can write $z = |z| e^{i \phi}$ where $\phi$ is the phase of the number $z$. This use of the word "phase" is misleading in this context. For instance, applying a "phase shift" would mean that we multiply $\cos \omega$ by some complex number $e^{i \phi'}$. That certainly wouldn't implement a phase shift of the sinusoidal wave, though, in the usual sense.

Comment: It's not wrong, it just refers to a different definition of phase. The complex phase arg(cos(t)) behaves exactly like described.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please ?

Comment: @Schimay, are you familiar with the polar representation of complex numbers? The phase of a complex number is just another name for the argument $\phi$ of its complex representation $z=|z| \exp(i \phi)$.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac how could the phase in whatever representation can change from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ ?

Comment: @AlexTP, it doesn't. Read the original post again. As the *argument of the cosine* crosses $\pi/2$, the phase jumps from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: @Schimay To put it another way: a negative number $M$ can be written as $|M|e^{j\pi}$; i.e. every real negative number has phase $\pi$.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac The OP sounds like a pretty standard presentation of the mathematics of real-valued sinusoidal waves. (I've seen a lot of this kind of stuff since I taught this kind of thing at university level for a number of years.) I've never seen anyone change it up and start talking about the value of $\cos \omega$ as a complex number in the middle of such a discussion.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski, we both don't know the context the statement was made in. The point is that the statement is not necessarily wrong and that giving the proper context to make it right is probably more helpful than insisting on it being wrong.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac I've edited my answer to address your point.